# What's the name of a list with only one element

Tags: java, list

What is the 'formal' name of a list that has only one element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java `Collections` calls this a singleton list, although I don't think this is a formal name.

[public static  List singletonList(T o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList%28T%29) *Returns an immutable list containing only the specified object. The returned list is serializable.*

I much prefer "single element list".

**Edit**: It appears that singleton [is a valid mathematical term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_%28mathematics%29) for a single element set.

Comment: I dont think singleton is the correct name. In the javadoc, `singleton` seems to mean "this object has only one copy". In my question, I'd like to stress the fact that it has only one element.

Comment: I agree. My guess is they just needed a short method name.

Answer (score 8):

I would call it a `unitList` (to avoid confusion with the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)) in mathematics a set containing
 only a single element is *also* known as a [unit set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_%28mathematics%29)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* call it singleton, since that is the correct mathematical term for a *set* with exactly one element. The term singleton, however, is used differently in computer science and commonly refers to an object, of which there is exactly one instance at any given time during the execution of the program, so it might be misleading or confusing, therefore i'd avoid using it for a one element set.

In mathematics, a set with exactly one element is also known as *unit set*. This is a name I'd go for.